# Implementing generic digits function

Tags: generics, rust

I wanted to implement `digits` function which returns a vector of individual digits for a given number. For example, `digits(12345)` should return `Vec[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

After struggling with some small issues, I ended up with the following code:

```
fn digits<T, R>(mut n: T) -> Vec<R> where 
    T: Num + Rem + DivAssign + FromPrimitive + Copy,
    R: Num + TryFrom<T>
{
    let zero = T::zero();
    let ten: T = T::from_i8(10).unwrap();
    let mut acc: Vec<R> = Vec::new();

    while n != zero {
        let d: R = R::try_from(n % ten).ok().unwrap();
        acc.push(d);
        n /= ten;
    }
    acc.reverse();
    acc
}
```

And this seems to working fine with most primitive integer types. The problem is that the input type `T` should implement `Copy`, I can't use this function for `BigInt` or `BigUint` as `Copy` is not implemented for them.

If I remove `Copy` trait from `T`, the compilation fails due to various errors with such messages as `bowwor of moved value: n` or `use of moved value: ten`.

How can fix this so it can work with primitive integers as well as `BigInt` and `BigUint`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that implements `Copy` does `Clone` too, also [`BigInt`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/struct.BigInt.html#impl-Clone) and `BigUint` implements `Clone`. So you could change the constraint to `Clone` instead and explicitly add any clone that you may need.

```rust
fn digits<T, R>(mut n: T) -> Vec<R> where 
    T: Num + Rem + DivAssign + FromPrimitive + Clone,
    R: Num + TryFrom<T>
{
...
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=75a0d5808634ab6654dca6169fee9b15)

Comment: Are you suggesting that I have to clone inside the loop? That doesn't sound like a good approach to me. Can't I borrow them (which I failed, though)?

Comment: @ntalbs, the other option is to use `&ten` instead, but you were copying it anyway...

Comment: @ntalbs, here is a first approach of using `&` references, but the problem is that the traits are not implemented to work with them, since output matches `&Self` instead of `Self`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1dc3746dfce221eae40e532805d8f28c